# Generating a large number of columns based on the unique values in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's assume that I have the following dataframe:

```
user_id | a1  | a2  | a3  | a4  | a5 | ... | a100
1       | 12  | 30  | 0   | 12  | 1  | ... | 21
2       | 2   | 13  | 18  | 13  | 13 | ... | 3
3       | 42  | 31  | 5   | 14  | 26 | ... | 41
4       | 1   | 9   | 10  | 15  | 20 | ... | 23
```

Based on this dataframe, I want to generate additional columns for any unique value in the columns of a1-a100. I think it is better to explain this with an example. Based on the dataframe above, I would have the following columns appended to the original dataframe:

```
1AndAbove | 2AndAbove | ... | 42AndAbove
5         | 4         | ... | 0
6         | 6         | ... | 0
6         | 6         | ... | 2
6         | 5         | ... | 0
```

For example, the values in the 42AndAbove column shows that only the 3rd user has a value equal to and grater than 42, and it has it twice.

I am able to do this one by one using the following code:

```
df['1AndAbove'] = (df > 1).astype(int).sum(axis=1)
```

However, this is very cumbersome if I need to generate 100 columns. I wonder if there is a more generic and elegant way of doing this?

Comment: You should be able do it in loop easily, not sure if there is vectorized way to do it.

Comment: @JohnGalt vectorized way below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUIC, you can filter `a*` columns first, and then loop through the range of 1-2 values check?

```
In [382]: df_a = df.filter(like='a')

In [385]: for x in range(1, 43):
     ...:     df['%sAndAbove' % x] = (df_a >= x).sum(axis=1)
     ...:
```

Result

```
In [386]: df
Out[386]:
   user_id  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a100  1AndAbove  2AndAbove  3AndAbove  \
0        1  12  30   0  12   1    21          5          4          4
1        2   2  13  18  13  13     3          6          6          5
2        3  42  31   5  14  26    41          6          6          6
3        4   1   9  10  15  20    23          6          5          5

      ...      33AndAbove  34AndAbove  35AndAbove  36AndAbove  37AndAbove  \
0     ...               0           0           0           0           0
1     ...               0           0           0           0           0
2     ...               2           2           2           2           2
3     ...               0           0           0           0           0

   38AndAbove  39AndAbove  40AndAbove  41AndAbove  42AndAbove
0           0           0           0           0           0
1           0           0           0           0           0
2           2           2           2           2           1
3           0           0           0           0           0

[4 rows x 49 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you sir, after you comment, I kinda figured out!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the vectorized way to do it:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=0).iloc[:,::-1].cumsum(axis=1).iloc[:,::-1]
Out[83]: 
         0   1   2   3   5   9   10  12  13  14  15  18  20  21  23  26  30  \
user_id                                                                       
1         6   5   4   4   4   4   4   4   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   1   1   
2         6   6   6   5   4   4   4   4   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   
3         6   6   6   6   6   5   5   5   5   5   4   4   4   4   4   4   3   
4         6   6   5   5   5   5   4   3   3   3   3   2   2   1   1   0   0   

         31  41  42  
user_id              
1         0   0   0  
2         0   0   0  
3         3   2   1  
4         0   0   0
```

Comment: Nice! Very interesting solution!